# change hidden field value according to string variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have string variable that received a value from a database , this variable is declared inside a servlet i want to know how can i pass the value of this String variable to that hidden field value , this hidden field is inside a jsp page

```
String flag = ub.getFlag(request);
```

hidden variable

```
<input  name="hiddenV"  type="hidden"  id="hiddenValue<%=ud.getUserId()%>"
value=""/>
```

Comment: Do you want to pass only flag or all ub data?

Comment: flag value only

Comment: I added as answer

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No , not worked :((

Comment: My answer must solve your problem. I think your doing some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet you must pass to jsp like following:

```
String flag = ub.getFlag(request);
request.setAttribute("flag", flag);
request.getRequestDispatcher("jspPageNameGoesHere").forward(request, response);
```

In jsp:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=request.getAttribute("flag")%>" me="hiddenV" />
```

Comment: You forgot something; `value="<%=request.getAttribute("flag")%>"` or `value="${requestScope.flag}"`